# Move database to another drive in same server

Tags: sql-server

I have installed MSSQL server 2008 in my server in `C:` drive and I want to move it to the `D:` drive completely. That means, database locations, installed location to move another drive with data. Is it possible to done this?

Note: *Detach method is only for move database. but I want to move whole installation and DB files to another drive.*

Comment: If you want to move the actual server install you have to uninstall and then reinstall. This is no different than any other windows application. You can't just move the installed files somewhere new.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Maybe try the DBA site.

Comment: @SeanLange If my source control is connected with SQL and the data is there. So, If i reinstall then need to add these data again manually or is it possible to take backup completely?

Answer (score 2):

It is easy and well documented to move data files (including master, model, tempdb,...) to other locations in MS-SQL Server. There is no supported approach to move the instalation (SQL Server binaries) to another drive / folder. I think even with manual manipulation of registry entries the SQL Server wouldn't come up again.

You should consider uninstall and new installation.

1. backup all databases including system databases as master, model ( SSISDB)
2. uninstall SQL Server using SQL Server installation center
3. uninstall SQL Server 2008 Browser component by using the Add or Remove Programs
4. install SQL Server with same instance name using SQL Server installation center; select new locations for binaries and data
5. restore backups

[This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/955499) article describes how to uninstall a stand-alone instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2008. When you follow the steps in this article, you also prepare the system so that you can reinstall SQL Server 2008

Comment: There is no point in restoring tempdb. It is recreated each time the instance restarts. SQL Server uninstall is not "clean." The OS may get confused if the new instance has the same name as the old, but is in a different location. I would suggest you install the new one first as a named instance, migrate application DBs, jobs etc one at a time, reconfiguring applications to point to the new instance. Once everything's moved uninstall the old instace.

Comment: @MichaelGreen totally agree with tempdb. but when i install a named Instance, it will share common files with default instance... right?

Comment: Yes, some files are shared between instances. Some files on the C: drive may be retained even after you uninstall the current instance. However, experience suggests some files and registry keys will remain even if the current instance is "removed" before the new instance is installed.

Comment: Of course if this is a personal / sandbox instance it's less important so just do what's easy and get on with life.

Comment: @MichaelGreen MS has [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/955499) a guideline how to uninstall and ensure a reinstallation of sqlserver2008. Following this guide even the common files folder can be changed during the installation of the new default instance. Do you think MS will give this guide for non production only?

Comment: From that linked article: "SQL Server Support team may recommend that you reinstall the operating system if the procedures outlined in this article do not help perform a clean uninstall."

Comment: SQL Server is like any installed Windows application and significantly more complex than most. And like any installed application it isn't a cut & paste operation.